# Latest file for download

Tags: symlink

I want to be able to have a generic link to the latest version on of file available for download to make things easier for clients.
Example: `http://server.web.net/Adium/Adium-1.5.10.4.pkg`
If it could be `http://server.web.net/Adium/LATEST`

The scripting side works fine, I just can't figure out the alias/link part.

```
latestfile=`find *.pkg | sort | tail -n 1`
echo $latestfile
```

This gets the correct file.

Comment: Not sure I follow your question, but the answer seems to be to store the latest file on the server as “latest.pkg” and replace it as often as necessary - the download script will always take that one...

Comment: What you yo mean you can't figure out the alias/link part?  When you create the link, what fails?

Comment: This question should not be put on hold because of "software development", as the rules clearly specify that shell scripting questions are encouraged here.

Comment: @user2720970 To answer your question: You can create the link using the following command: "ln -s $latestfile LATEST".

Comment: @jksoegaard now that the question is reopened, you might want to write/expand that into an answer.

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that `find *.pkg | sort` sorts by name, not by date, so you rely on "sane" filenames here (and nobody `touch`ing any old files).

Comment: Just stressing that `find *.pkg | sort` is not sorting by the version numbers of the packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a symbolik link using the following command:

`ln -s "$latestfile" LATEST`

When you access LATEST you will really access the actual file, so no copying of data takes place - and no extra space is used.

Depending on your web server, you might need to allow the use of symbolic links for that directory.

Comment: `ln -sf ...` might be safer to avoid errors if a LATEST already exists